# Хочу подключиться к БД Heroku Postgrresql через модуль asyncpg python

Tags: postgresql, aiogram

Я хочу подключить своего бота на aiogram к бд heroku postgre. Я получил ссылку вида postgres://.....
Не понимаю, с помощью какого метода я должен эт сделать.
Получаю такую ошибку:

```
2021-07-07T10:37:05.317336+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-07-07T10:37:05.317373+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 4, in <module>
2021-07-07T10:37:05.317539+00:00 app[worker.1]:     from data.config import DBConfig
2021-07-07T10:37:05.317567+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/data/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
2021-07-07T10:37:05.318163+00:00 app[worker.1]:     from . import config
2021-07-07T10:37:05.318193+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/data/config.py", line 13, in <module>
2021-07-07T10:37:05.318574+00:00 app[worker.1]:     conn = asyncpg.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require',)
2021-07-07T10:37:05.318678+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sslmode'
```

Код подключения:

```
DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
conn = asyncpg.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, метод `connect` в библиотеке asyncpg - асинхронный, и перед вызовом асинхронной функции должен указываться оператор `await`.

Во-вторых, интерпретатор говорит, что Вы передаёте в метод `connect` аргумент, который там не нужен. То есть, вместо `asyncpg.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require',)` нужно использовать `asyncpg.connect(DATABASE_URL)`.

Ну и в-втретьих, пример взят из [официальной документации](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html).

```py
DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
conn = await asyncpg.connect(DATABASE_URL)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]